# HTMl Table Width issue when added new table below to show effect like freeze pane

Tags: html, css

I using the code to create header freeze table but the width of both the tables are not matching. Here is the Code

```html
<div id="view_feedback_table">
<table id="crosstable"  border =1  cellpadding="6px" style="margin-top: 30px;TEXT-ALIGN: left;float:left;width:1200px;BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="9" style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: #1b4a84;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Response</span>
</th>
<th style="text-align: right;">
Download
</th>
</tr>
<tr style="color: white; background-color: rgb(31, 73, 125);">
<th style="width: 10%;">Activity Code</th>
<th style="width: 10%;">No of Completed Associates</th>
<th style="width: 10%;">No of Participants Submitted Feedback</th>
<th style="width: 7%;">Instructor</th>
<th style="width: 7%;">Courseware</th>
<th style="width: 7%;">Environment</th>
<th style="width: 8%;">Learner Support</th>
<th style="width: 7%;">Overall</th>
<th style="width: 10%;">Overall Activity Feedback</th>
<th style="width: 8%;">Overall Activity NPS</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<table id="crosstable" border =1 cellpadding="6px" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left;float:left;width:1200px;BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse;display: block;max-height: 50px;overflow-y: auto;">
<tbody>
<tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: white;">
<td style="width: 10%;">
Activity_Code1
</td>
<td style="width: 10%;">No_
<wbr>of_
<wbr>Completed_
<wbr>Associates
</td>
<td style="width: 10%;">No_
<wbr>of_
<wbr>Participants_
<wbr>Submitted_
<wbr>Feedback
</td>
<td style="width: 7%;">Instructor</td>
<td style="width: 7%;">Courseware</td>
<td style="width: 7%;">Environment</td>
<td style="width: 8%;">Learner_
<wbr>Support
</td>
<td style="width: 7%;">Overall</td>
<td style="width: 10%;">Overall_
<wbr>Activity_
<wbr>Feedback
</td>
<td style="width: 8%;">Overall_
<wbr>Activity_
<wbr>NPS
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: rgb(220, 230, 241);">
<td>
Activity_Code2
</td>
<td>No_
<wbr>of_
<wbr>Completed_
<wbr>Associates
</td>
<td>No_
<wbr>of_
<wbr>Participants_
<wbr>Submitted_
<wbr>Feedback
</td>
<td>Instructor</td>
<td>Courseware</td>
<td>Environment</td>
<td>Learner_
<wbr>Support
</td>
<td>Overall</td>
<td>Overall_
<wbr>Activity_
<wbr>Feedback
</td>
<td>Overall_
<wbr>Activity_
<wbr>NPS
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: white;">
<td>
Activity_Code3
</td>
<td>No_
<wbr>of_
<wbr>Completed_
<wbr>Associates
</td>
<td>No_
<wbr>of_
<wbr>Participants_
<wbr>Submitted_
<wbr>Feedback
</td>
<td>Instructor</td>
<td>Courseware</td>
<td>Environment</td>
<td>Learner_
<wbr>Support
</td>
<td>Overall</td>
<td>Overall_
<wbr>Activity_
<wbr>Feedback
</td>
<td>Overall_
<wbr>Activity_
<wbr>NPS
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Any suggestions to make this correct. I need freeze header effect so can't use the same table to adjust the width.

Thanks it worked but still have some minor alignment issue when the auto scroll comes into the picture. Is there any way to adjust that one too in the code.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div style="position: fixed;background:#fff;z-index: 999;">
    <table id="crosstable" cellpadding="6px" border=1 style="margin-top: 30px;TEXT-ALIGN: left;width:1200px;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" style="text-align: center;">
                <span style="color: #1b4a84;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">L1 Feedback Response</span>
            </th>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <a onclick="download excel(&quot;default&quot;,&quot;default&quot;,&quot;AC&quot;)">
                <img src="/pentaho-style/1235/images/excel icon.png" title="Download" style="height: 24px;">
                </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color: white;background-color: rgb(31, 73, 125);/* position: fixed; */">
            <td style="width: 10%;">Activity Code</th>
            <td style="width: 10%;">No of Completed Associates</th>
            <td style="width: 10%;">No of Participants Submitted Feedback</th>
            <td style="width: 7%;">Instructor</th>
            <td style="width: 7%;">Courseware</th>
            <td style="width: 7%;">Environment</th>
            <td style="width: 8%;">Learner Support</th>
            <td style="width: 7%;">Overall</th>
            <td style="width: 10%;">Overall Activity Feedback</th>
            <td style="width: 8%;">Overall Activity NPS</th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:125px;">
    <table id="crosstable" cellpadding="6px" border=1 style="TEXT-ALIGN: left;max-height: 500px;width:1200px;">
        <tbody>
        <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: white;">
            <td  style="width: 10%;">
                Activity Code2
            </td>
            <td  style="width: 10%;">No_<wbr>of_<wbr>Completed_<wbr>Associates</td>
            <td  style="width: 10%;">No_<wbr>of_<wbr>Participants_<wbr>Submitted_<wbr>Feedback</td>
            <td style="width: 7%;">Instructor</td>
            <td  style="width: 7%;">Courseware</td>
            <td style="width: 7%;">Environment</td>
            <td style="width: 8%;">Learner_<wbr>Support</td>
            <td style="width: 7%;">Overall</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">Overall_<wbr>Activity_<wbr>Feedback</td>
            <td style="width: 8%;">Overall_<wbr>Activity_<wbr>NPS</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

`<td>` content with "underscores" like `No_of_Participants_Submitted_Feedback` are unbreakable, therefore it would push the width of the columns. So you might want to use space instead of underscores.

If you must have the underscores, add `<wbr>` after every underscore like this `No_<wbr>of_<wbr>Participants_<wbr>Submitted_<wbr>Feedback`.

Also note that you missed `%` in `<td style="width: 7;">Environment</td>`.

Just by doing this, you would see a huge change in your result, then you can tweak your codes to match perfectly.

Comment: how to avoid the width to push even though underscores are present ?

Comment: Add `<wbr>` after every "underscore" like this `No_<wbr>of_<wbr>Completed_<wbr>Associates`

Comment: It working but stil some align issue is there... you can preview in code snippet

Comment: I've added code snippet. Note that `position:fixed` would only works for vertical scroll and won't work for horizontal scroll.

Comment: Hi i have updated the code, now just minor scroll issue can be adjust that one too ?